# Select records if the count of related records is less than a number

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables, `Article` and `Comments`.
Now I want to know the number of articles which have less than 5 comments.
How can I do that?

Articles:

```
id | author_id | title | cotent
```

Comments:

```
id | article_id | author_id | content
```

Edit: the original question is about larger than, but now I actually want less than (e.g., <5). If there is no comment record for an article, it seems this article is not listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both table to get the comments of articles and then group it by article id to know comment count of each article.

Try out this:

```
select art.id,count(*) as comment_count  
from articles art 
inner join comments com on art.id=com.article_id
group by art.id
having comment_count>5
```

For articles having comments <= 5:

```
select art.id,count(*) as comment_count  
from articles art 
left join comments com on art.id=com.article_id
group by art.id
having comment_count<=5
```

Comment: I want the case that comment is less than 5, as edited. Will this include the case that there is no comment records for an article? It seems no results returned if there isn't any comments for an article.

Comment: @mrmoment: I have added query for less than 5 also. check once.

Comment: If in Articles an article with id=3 exists, but there isn't any comments for article_id=3 in Comments. This query will not return article id=3 in my test.

Comment: @mrmoment just make the inner join a left join

Comment: @Terminus: Thanks for your solution :)

Comment: @mrmoment: Please check the update query as suggested by the Terminus

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    articles a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c ON a.id=c.article_id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

this will return `id` of all `articles` having more than 5 comments, with their respective comment count